# Error during startup: b43-phy0 unsupported phy

Tags: 14.04

When my machine starts up, I get the following messages:

```
[17.789158] b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY(Analog 10, Type 8 (LCN), Revision 1)
[21.656204] brcmsmac bcma:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[21.656266] brcmsmac bcma:0: brcms_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211

Looks like the wireless driver needs an updating

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here. Please describe what needs to be done to update the driver within Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This message derives from my Broadcom BCM4313 wireless chip. The crucial question is: does your wifi work or not?
Although I get this message at startup, my wifi works flawlessly. Every attempt to make the message disappear, ended in nothing or a non-working wifi. So, if you wifi works, I recommend to ignore the message (it appears with different kernels and on different linux distros).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because my computer's Broadcom wi-fi chip was not supported by the included open-source `bcma` kernel module driver. No wireless connection appeared when I ran `ip link`, so this definitely wasn't a transient error message. I identified the wi-fi chip by running the `lspci -k` command (note: might have to use `lsusb` if the chip is connected via USB instead of PCI), then finding the line (usually the last) saying:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 855c
    Kernel driver in use: bcma
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

The wi-fi chip is a BCM4352, and we're trying to use the `bcma` kernel module to interface with it. According to [this page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43) on kernel.org, the BCM4352 chip is not supported by the default `bcma` kernel module; you have to use the restrictively-licensed `broadcom-wl` kernel module instead. The installation process for this driver varies depending on your distro; [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Broadcom_wireless) were the directions I used for Arch Linux.

Once you install `broadcom-wl` you'll have two kernel modules competing to service your wi-fi chip - `wl` and `bcma`. You can see this by running `lspci -k` and seeing:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 855c
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

To prevent conflicts you'll want to blacklist the `bcma` kernel module. I did this by following the directions on the Arch Linux wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_module#Blacklisting), creating a file at `/etc/modprobe.d/nobcma.conf` containing:

```
# Do not load the 'bcma' module on boot.
blacklist bcma
```

After rebooting you can run `dmesg | grep bcma` to check that it isn't loaded, and `dmesg | grep wl` to ensure `wl` is loaded (along with some messages about the kernel being tainted by the proprietary code!)

I can now run `ip link` and see the wireless link exists:

```
...
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:27:1e:30:26:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```